# Router & Routee's dispatcher

Tags: java, akka

I am confused about the dispatcher settings of Router and routee. At the time of creation of router if I use

```
ActorRef router1 =_system.actorOf(FromConfig.getInstance().props(Props.create(MyActor.class).withDispatcher("my-dispatcher")),"MyRouter");
```

So this dispatcher is being used by all the routees. What about the dispatcher being used by the router. In my application.conf if I do something like

```
akka.actor.deployment {
    /MyRouter{
        router = round-robin-pool
        nr-of-instances = 5
        dispatcher = my-dispatcher
    }
```

How to check if this dispatcher is being used (if this is the right way to do it) by the router.
Also how can I set what kind of dispatcher should be used by the routees using akka.actor.depolyment in config.